# Python short time format

Tags: python, datetime, time, format, timedelta

Is there a simple way in Python to format a time (delta) as follows:

```
10:11:12 -> 10:11:12
09:10:11 ->  9:10:11 
00:10:11 ->    10:11
00:09:10 ->     9:10
00:00:10 ->       10 (or maybe as 0:10)
00:00:09 ->        9 (or maybe as 0:09)
```

I.e. suppressing leading zeros and separators 
(but maybe not when time delta is < 1 minute)

Comment: What should be the output in case of "10:00:10"?

Comment: @anonymous, pretty sure exactly as is.

Comment: 10:00:10 I think, because there is some leading non-zero digits i.e hour=10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the string, you could just *lstrip* any leading colons or 0's:

```
In [3]: "00:00:10".lstrip("0:")
Out[3]: '10'

In [4]: "09:10:11".lstrip("0:")
Out[4]: '9:10:11'

In [5]: "10:10:11".lstrip("0:")
Out[5]: '10:10:11'
```

It is only gong to strip as long as we have a 0 or : and stop as soon as we find anything other than the two chars. One case you might want to catch is `"00:00:00"`. In that situation I have no idea what you expect.

If you are trying to also right align, you can *rjust* the result:

```
In [18]: "00:00:19".lstrip("0:").rjust(8)
Out[18]: '      19'

In [19]: "10:00:19".lstrip("0:").rjust(8)
Out[19]: '10:00:19'

In [20]: "09:00:19".lstrip("0:").rjust(8)
Out[20]: ' 9:00:19'
```

Of use *str.format* as @C.LECLERC commented.

```
"{:>8}".format("00:10:11".lstrip("0:"))
```

You just need to call *str* on the timedeltas if you are not going into days:

```
In [6]: from datetime import timedelta
   ...: 
   ...: td1,td2,td3 = timedelta(hours=10, minutes=10), timedelta(seconds=10),tim
   ...: edelta(minutes=9, seconds=10)
   ...: for t in (td1, td2, td3):
   ...:     print(str(t))
   ...:     print(str(t).lstrip("0:"))
   ...:     
10:10:00
10:10:00
0:00:10
10
0:09:10
9:10
```

If you want to set a minimum time period i.e >= 1 minute:

```
from datetime import timedelta
mn = timedelta(minutes=1)

td1,td2,td3 = timedelta(hours=10, minutes=10), timedelta(seconds=10),timedelta(minutes=9, seconds=10)
for t in (td1, td2, td3):
    if t >= mn:
         print(str(t).lstrip("0:"))
    else:
        print(str(t))
```

Comment: WOW nice. BTW i would add some more format to fit the question perfectly : `"{:>8}".format("00:10:11".lstrip("0:"))`

Comment: @C.LECLERC.  I don't know if it is just a visual representation for the question or the OP wants the string aligned but sire that would work fine.

Comment: That `.rjust(8)` is just ... better in all terms

Comment: I choose this as the accepted answer because it was the first one talking about the nice .lstrip("0:") way - even though the solution I use is the next one by @brianpck  that also describes how to "get" the string from the timedelta object mentioned in my question. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Phiplex, you have timedelata objects?

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham  Yes. And I also like to mention that the situation with  `"00:00:00"` and also with timedelta less than 1 minute talked about in my question turns out to be no problem because in my application every timedelta that occur will always be larger than 1 minute.

Comment: Are they all within a certain range or also over days?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Always larger than one minute and normally less than one or a few hours. Not sure yet, but in some very special cases maybe larger than one or maybe more days.

Comment: @Phiplex, well if under 24 hours, all you need is to call str.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: Please explain for a noob

Comment: @Phiplex. see the edit. Calling str on the timedelta will give you formatted output that you just need to lstrip. The `mn = timedelta(minutes=1)` sets a minimum threshold to lstrip any zeros

Comment: No worries, also in the case of the special cases all you need is to set a mx timedelta and if you are between the mn and mx you just use str, else you use a conversion function, there are numerous methods on SO to convert 24+ to hours, minutes etc..

Answer (score 2):

There may be a more elegant way of doing this, but here's a start, assuming that you are actually dealing with a `timedelta` object:

```
from datetime import timedelta
x = timedelta(hours = 10, minutes=11, seconds=12)

print('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(x.seconds // 3600,
                                    x.seconds // 60 % 60, 
                                    x.seconds % 60)
                            .lstrip('0:'))
```

Used with your examples:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> for h, m, s in [(10,11,12), (9,10,11), (0,10,11), (0,9,10), (0,0,10), (0,0,9)]:
...     td = timedelta(hours = h, minutes=m, seconds=s)
...     print('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(td.seconds // 3600,
...                                         td.seconds // 60 % 60,
...                                         td.seconds % 60)
...                                 .lstrip('0:'))
...
10:11:12
9:10:11
10:11
9:10
10
9
```

Answer (score 1):

short answer: No there is no builtin datetime command to do this..
long answer: you can use a relatively simple set of conditional statements to generate your own string by testing if there is an hours component, then a minutes component then a seconds component:

```python
import datetime

td = datetime.timedelta(hours=3, minutes=23, seconds=13)

if td.seconds >= 3600:
    print "{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(td.seconds//3600, (td.seconds%3600)//60, td.seconds%60)
elif td.seconds >= 60:
    print "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(td.seconds//60, td.seconds%60)
elif td.seconds >= 0:
    print "0:{:02d}".format(td.seconds)
else:
    print "there is no time left.. RUN!"
```